# Not able to perform click event on dynamic <a> by using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Code used to display table dynamically

```
$('#showAll').click(function(){     
        $('#empList tr').remove();
        $('#empList').append("<tr><th>EmpID</th><th>EmpName</th><th>EmpSalary</th></tr>");
        $.getJSON(rootURL, function(data) {
            if(data.employee.length > 1){
                for (var i in data.employee) {              
                    $('#empList').append('<tr><td><a class="a" href="#" value="' + data.employee[i].empID + '">'+data.employee[i].empID+'</a></td><td> ' + data.employee[i].empName+ '</td><td> ' + data.employee[i].empSal+'</td></tr>');
                }
            }else{
                $('#empList').append('<tr><td><a class="a" href="#" value="'+data.employee.empID+'">'+ data.employee.empID + '</a></td><td>' + data.employee.empName+ '</td><td>' + data.employee.empSal+'</td></tr>');
            }
            });
    });
```

code used to perform click event on  tag when i try to click on hyper link it is not performing any action:

```
$('#empList a').click(function() {
    alert("inr");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to perform click on dynamic link. look code bellow:

```
$('body').on('click', '#empList a', function() {
    alert("inr");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

After appending the anchor tag to Dom, bind the click event to it.

```
$('#empList a').bind("click", function (e) {
    alert("inr");    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but browser has not responding for this code